Evaluation of all noncommutative polynomials at a point

Let $\mathcal{P}$ be the set of all noncommutative polynomials in $n$ free variables over the field $\mathbb{R}$. Let $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n \in M_k(\mathbb{R})$ be fixed. Is there any description of the set of all polynomial evaluations $\{p(X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n)| p \in \mathcal{P}\}$?

I know a little about the ongoing research on the range of a given noncommutative polynomial. But I have not seen anything related to evaluation of all polynomials at a point.

It’s just the algebra generated by $X_1, \cdots, X_n$ (or the $\ast$-algebra generated by them, if $\mathcal{P}$ consists of noncommutative $\ast$-polynomials).
